# SAS Linux Multiple X commands

Tags: linux, sas, sh

I need to run multiple X commands(Linux backend) in a SAS Macro. Each X command should execute without waiting for the previous command to finish.  At present Code does not go to second X command till first X command is not finished. Please help.

Example:

```
%macro abc;

X '<Linux Command1>' ;
X '<Linux Command2>' ;
X '<Linux Command3>' ;

%mend abc;
```

Comment: Use nohup if you really don't need to wait

Answer (score 3):

You can use `&` to allow the command to process in the background.

```
X '<Linux Command1> &' ;
X '<Linux Command2> &' ;
X '<Linux Command3> &' ;
```

If you want the commands to keep running even after you end SAS look into the **nohup** command.